# Как называется алгоритм поиска главной сцены на фотографии?

Tags: алгоритм, изображения, golang

Есть ли специальное название у алгоритма, который ищет главную часть на фотографии.

Нужно, чтобы правильно автоматически кропнуть изображение.

Где можно почитать про эти алгоритмы? А может уже есть готовый алгоритм написанный на Go?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел на Go вот такой алгоритм https://github.com/muesli/smartcrop

Также там есть ссылка на этот алгоритм на Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это называется "smart crop".

Comment: По крайней мере, именно так подобные алгоритмы называют в библиотеках для Python.

Comment: кстати гуглил smart crop но ничего по теме не нагуглил

Answer (score 0):

Saliency, вроде бы, называется. Для Go, к сожалению, не подскажу, но в C++/OpenCV 3-beta такая вещь присутствует.